# How to Merge javascript into another javascript code?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a webpage with html and python using the flask web framework.

I was trying to create a dropdown select option, that will redirect the user to the login and the registration page.

I want to implement the below javascript code:

```
function goToNewPage() {
    var url = document.getElementById('list').value;
    if (url != 'none') {
        window.location = url;
    }
}
```

into this javascript code and want to be able to  style my select option and make it rediret the user to the login page, like wise for to the register page.

```js
var x, i, j, l, ll, selElmnt, a, b, c;
/*look for any elements with the class "custom-select":*/
x = document.getElementsByClassName("login-box");
l = x.length;
for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
  selElmnt = x[i].getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
  ll = selElmnt.length;
  /*for each element, create a new DIV that will act as the selected item:*/
  a = document.createElement("DIV");
  a.setAttribute("class", "select-selected");
  a.innerHTML = selElmnt.options[selElmnt.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
  x[i].appendChild(a);
  /*for each element, create a new DIV that will contain the option list:*/
  b = document.createElement("DIV");
  b.setAttribute("class", "select-items select-hide");
  for (j = 1; j < ll; j++) {
    /*for each option in the original select element,
    create a new DIV that will act as an option item:*/
    c = document.createElement("DIV");
    c.innerHTML = selElmnt.options[j].innerHTML;
    c.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      /*when an item is clicked, update the original select box,
      and the selected item:*/
      var y, i, k, s, h, sl, url, yl;
      s = this.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
      sl = s.length;
      h = this.parentNode.previousSibling;
      for (i = 0; i < sl; i++) {
        if (s.options[i].innerHTML == this.innerHTML) {
          s.selectedIndex = i;
          h.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
          y = this.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("same-as-selected");
          yl = y.length;
          for (k = 0; k < yl; k++) {
            y[k].removeAttribute("class");
          }
          this.setAttribute("class", "same-as-selected");
          break;
        }
      }
      h.click();
    });
    b.appendChild(c);
  }
  x[i].appendChild(b);
  a.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    /*when the select box is clicked, close any other select boxes,
    and open/close the current select box:*/
    e.stopPropagation();
    closeAllSelect(this);
    this.nextSibling.classList.toggle("select-hide");
    this.classList.toggle("select-arrow-active");
  });
}

function closeAllSelect(elmnt) {
  /*a function that will close all select boxes in the document,
  except the current select box:*/
  var x, y, i, xl, yl, arrNo = [];
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("select-items");
  y = document.getElementsByClassName("select-selected");
  xl = x.length;
  yl = y.length;
  for (i = 0; i < yl; i++) {
    if (elmnt == y[i]) {
      arrNo.push(i)
    } else {
      y[i].classList.remove("select-arrow-active");
    }
  }
  for (i = 0; i < xl; i++) {
    if (arrNo.indexOf(i)) {
      x[i].classList.add("select-hide");
    }
  }
}
/*if the user clicks anywhere outside the select box,
then close all select boxes:*/
document.addEventListener("click", closeAllSelect);
```

```css
<style>
/*the container must be positioned relative:*/

.login-box {
  position: relative;
  font-family: Arial;
}

.login-box select {
  display: none;
  /*hide original SELECT element:*/
}

.select-selected {
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
}


/*style the arrow inside the select element:*/

.select-selected:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: 14px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 6px solid transparent;
  border-color: #fff transparent transparent transparent;
}


/*point the arrow upwards when the select box is open (active):*/

.select-selected.select-arrow-active:after {
  border-color: transparent transparent #fff transparent;
  top: 7px;
}


/*style the items (options), including the selected item:*/

.select-items div,
.select-selected {
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-color: transparent transparent rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
}


/*style items (options):*/

.select-items {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 99;
}


/*hide the items when the select box is closed:*/

.select-hide {
  display: none;
}

.select-items div:hover,
.same-as-selected {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

</style>
```

```html
<div class="login-box">
  <form>
    <select id="list" name="list" accesskey="target" data-placeholder="Login">
      <option value='login.html' onclick="goToNewPage()">Login</option>
      <option value="register.html" onclick="goToNewPage()">Register</option>
    </select>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried just encasing it in `<script></script>` and putting inline with your html?

Comment: Yes have tried it to the (function goToNewPage()) is not responding, I encasing it and I put the other JavaScript which style the option in a separate file call login.js but the (function goToNewPage()) is not working, which if I remove the other JavaScript and encasing only the (function goToNewPage ()) it do work, but the select option is not styled properly...

Comment: Can we see your HTML for how you are initializing the script files? The dependency should be loaded first. I also see you are manipulating the `DOM`, which means you will need to defer the dependency script or execute it at the end of your document.

Comment: After I define my div function as started above inside my html file, I now then add a script encasing below it that contains the goToNewPage function, which worked the way I wanted when tested, but the select options are not styled, so I needed something cool which I decided to style the select options with the above css file as started above, which the select option  refuse to show up at all, which I decide to make it show up with the above started JavaScript in a separate js file which I make my server to serve the file for me which work the way I wanted, but I noticed that the goToNewPage..

Comment: (Continuation...) function is not working as of when tested without styling the select options, instead of redirecting the user to the value it only close the unselected options and replace the selected as the title of the select options, which I want it to redirect the users to the value when any option is been clicked on... Am not that good at JavaScript that much, I will very grateful if you can help me add the goToNewPage function JavaScript code into the JavaScript that allows the select options to display as been styled...

Comment: Matthew R. Dangle, I won't mind if u can help me with the correct (code) way to initialize the script file and make it work as aspected. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `onselect` on the `select` element rather than `onclick` on the `option` element.

```js
function goToNewPage() {
  var url = document.getElementById('list').value;
  if (url != 'none') {
    alert(window.location = url);
  }
}

var x, i, j, l, ll, selElmnt, a, b, c;
/*look for any elements with the class "custom-select":*/
x = document.getElementsByClassName("login-box");
l = x.length;
for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
  selElmnt = x[i].getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
  ll = selElmnt.length;
  /*for each element, create a new DIV that will act as the selected item:*/
  a = document.createElement("DIV");
  a.setAttribute("class", "select-selected");
  a.innerHTML = selElmnt.options[selElmnt.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
  x[i].appendChild(a);
  /*for each element, create a new DIV that will contain the option list:*/
  b = document.createElement("DIV");
  b.setAttribute("class", "select-items select-hide");
  for (j = 1; j < ll; j++) {
    /*for each option in the original select element,
    create a new DIV that will act as an option item:*/
    c = document.createElement("DIV");
    c.innerHTML = selElmnt.options[j].innerHTML;
    c.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      /*when an item is clicked, update the original select box,
      and the selected item:*/
      var y, i, k, s, h, sl, url, yl;
      s = this.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
      sl = s.length;
      h = this.parentNode.previousSibling;
      for (i = 0; i < sl; i++) {
        if (s.options[i].innerHTML == this.innerHTML) {
          s.selectedIndex = i;
          h.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
          y = this.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("same-as-selected");
          yl = y.length;
          for (k = 0; k < yl; k++) {
            y[k].removeAttribute("class");
          }
          this.setAttribute("class", "same-as-selected");
          break;
        }
      }
      h.click();
    });
    b.appendChild(c);
  }
  x[i].appendChild(b);
  a.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    /*when the select box is clicked, close any other select boxes,
    and open/close the current select box:*/
    e.stopPropagation();
    closeAllSelect(this);
    this.nextSibling.classList.toggle("select-hide");
    this.classList.toggle("select-arrow-active");
  });
}

function closeAllSelect(elmnt) {
  /*a function that will close all select boxes in the document,
  except the current select box:*/
  var x, y, i, xl, yl, arrNo = [];
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("select-items");
  y = document.getElementsByClassName("select-selected");
  xl = x.length;
  yl = y.length;
  for (i = 0; i < yl; i++) {
    if (elmnt == y[i]) {
      arrNo.push(i)
    } else {
      y[i].classList.remove("select-arrow-active");
    }
  }
  for (i = 0; i < xl; i++) {
    if (arrNo.indexOf(i)) {
      x[i].classList.add("select-hide");
    }
  }
}
/*if the user clicks anywhere outside the select box,
then close all select boxes:*/
document.addEventListener("click", closeAllSelect);
```

```css
<style>
/*the container must be positioned relative:*/

.login-box {
  position: relative;
  font-family: Arial;
}

.login-box select {
  display: none;
  /*hide original SELECT element:*/
}

.select-selected {
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
}


/*style the arrow inside the select element:*/

.select-selected:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: 14px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 6px solid transparent;
  border-color: #fff transparent transparent transparent;
}


/*point the arrow upwards when the select box is open (active):*/

.select-selected.select-arrow-active:after {
  border-color: transparent transparent #fff transparent;
  top: 7px;
}


/*style the items (options), including the selected item:*/

.select-items div,
.select-selected {
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-color: transparent transparent rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
}


/*style items (options):*/

.select-items {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 99;
}


/*hide the items when the select box is closed:*/

.select-hide {
  display: none;
}

.select-items div:hover,
.same-as-selected {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

</style>
```

```html
<div class="login-box">
  <form>
    <select id="list" name="list" accesskey="target" data-placeholder="Login" onchange="goToNewPage()">
      <option value="none">(select)</option>
      <option value='login.html'>Login</option>
      <option value="register.html">Register</option>
    </select>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: still the same thing happing here, i want it to redirect the user to the login page, not just to close up the unselected options and display the selected one! thanks for your responds, i will be very greatful if you can help  me solve this puzzle @AutinFrance. THANKS